# Is there any less awkward way of saying "response to to a step change in the amplitude of the input waveform"?

Tags: terminology

Exactly what the title says. I'm writing a technical report on a project I'm doing and I have one circuit which takes in a sine wave of various amplitudes, does a bunch of stuff to it and produces output that's steady for a steady input wave amplitude.

I'm tempted to say "step response" but in isn't that strictly speaking. And "response to to a step change in the amplitude of the input waveform" just sounds super awkward and too long to be using all the time while referring to the responses.

Comment: [Step response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_response) is the right term.  To make it clearer for the readers of your report, you can provide the long version in a footnote.

Comment: Also, I think you have one too many "to"s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend **envelope step response**. It's not terribly elegant, but it does convey the meaning you're trying for. The other possibility that seems possible is **tone burst response**.

Answer (score 2):

> “response to a step change in the amplitude of the input waveform”?

"Response" implies a reaction to an "input change" making your sentence now: -

“response to a step ” or "step response"